# Get rid of projection in the query Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

In this query I am trying to get all messages that were not written by a user, and the date of creation of which is greater than chat_user.max_read_message.

But there is a projection in my query that I would like to remove, just below I indicated the projection. How can I rewrite the query so that it is more optimal and does not contain the projection?

```js
db.chatsusers.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            chat_id: {
                $in: ["ad0a3405-1a16-48f9-93e6-51b17a7283e2", "22e1e6f1-459a-4ed1-bc8f-c9947492972d"],
            },
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "message",
            localField: "chat_id",
            foreignField: "chat_id",
            let: { chat_id: "$chat_id", max_read_date: "$max_read_date" },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: {
                            $and: [
                                { $eq: ["$chat_id", "$$chat_id"] },
                                { $ne: ["$from_id", "63f5002735bb916dab3f2b1e"] },
                                { $gt: ["$create_date", "$$max_read_date"] },
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                }
            ],
            as: "messages"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            chat_id: 1,
            message_count: { $size: "$messages" },
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$chat_id",
            message_count: { $sum: "$message_count" },
        },
    },
    {
        $sort: { "message_count": -1 },
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            chat_id: "$_id",
            message_count: 1,
        },
    },
])
```

how can I get rid of the projection in the query and make it even easier?

```js
{
    $project: {
      chat_id: 1,
      message_count: {
        $size: "$messages"
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$chat_id",
      message_count: {
        $sum: "$message_count"
      },
      
    },
    
  },
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dufPDpjImSD)

Comment: Why do you want to remove the `$project`? It could be helpful as it reduces number of fields in intermediate results. Nevertheless, you can simply put the `$size` into the next `$group` stage like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zqtTUWsU_WY)